# P/Invoke and unmanaged DLL state

Tags: .net, c, pinvoke

I have an assembly and an unmanaged DLL. I tried to use a static variable in the unmanaged DLL but it does not seem to survive between calls from the assembly.

I wonder whether static variables in unmanaged DLLs can exist between P/Invoke calls, possibly I miss something in my code. If not, what is the best way to store a state for such an unmanaged DLL if a global static variable is not an option?

Comment: A static variable should live as long as the DLL is not unloaded. So this should be working. Can you show some code?

Comment: @Codo I checked it one more time and now it is _working_, so I missed something. I'm so sorry I posted this question, it was just easy to believe for me that a variable didn't live between calls. Should I close this question? By the way, is the unmanaged DLL loaded once during the first pinvoke and unloaded when an application exists?I came to believe than the DLL was loaded  and unloaded by CLR after a pinvoke.

Comment: Loading and unloading a DLL is rather expensive. So I don't think it happens very often. But I don't know when it really happens. It might be worth another question on SO.

Comment: From the discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/c73d5cb8-fc3b-4425-9cd8-2495e9ac110c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920261/whats-the-lifetime-of-an-unmanaged-dll-once-its-been-pinovked-from-managed-code) it looks like the native dll stays loaded after the p/invoke.

Answer (score 3):

The .Net runtime will typically not unload your pinvoke DLLs on its own, as it has no way of knowing if its safe to do so, like if they contain state, including and globals like static strings or whatever.

Its not clear in you question wether you mean a static on the .Net side or a static / const on the unmanaged side.  If you mean one on the managed side, then its not guarenteed to exist after the call comes back, if its been marshaled, and depending on the setup for the call on the managed side unless you follow some very specific rules. If its just a plan number then it doesnt matter so I'm going to assume its a string or someother more complex structure.

As an example, if the callee is a c function in a dll that expects a ansi string, and you let pinvoke take a C# string, it will marshal the c# unicode string to an asni string for you, and will expect to get to reclaim that memory after the call is done, even if that string came from a C# static. Even if that wasnt the case, any pointer to managed memory should be considered invalid after the call unless you are pinning that memory.

[Here is some rope to hang yourself :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Use this with care. This will anchor managed memory indefinately, and I woulodnt suggest doing this. The DLL having its own copy of a string, or managed side having its own copy, wouldnt be the greatest programming crime ever committed. And as a practical matter would be much faster if they each have one in thier own heap, if it is indeed intended to be static. The C function needs to make its own copy before the call returns.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of state depends entirely on the unmanaged code in question, it is up to that what it does with it's static variables, once you call into it, you have no control over it and are bound by the rules of the library in question.

One commenter suggests you can remove a static by unloading the library that contains it, this isn't possible in all cases ( you can't unload the main c library ) but may work for you.