# C# Pinvoke and reloading a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I'm trying to unload a C++ DLL from my C# program and then reload it and useits functions.
for the unloading part i Used this answer:
[Unload a DLL loaded using DllImport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445536/unload-a-dll-loaded-using-dllimport)

In order to reload it I used the LoadLibrary function.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        [DllImport("TestLibrary.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetValue();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int val = GetValue();
            IntPtr p2 = LoadLibrary("TestLibrary.dll");

            bool isFree = FreeLibrary(p2);
            isFree = FreeLibrary(p2);
            p2 = LoadLibrary("TestLibrary.dll");
            val = GetValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that pinvoke still works when I reload the module.
Isn't the module supposed to be loaded to a different part of the memory?
Can I do it the way I did or am I going to have trouble with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you unload and reload a module it might load at a different address. Or it might load at the same address. It's up to the system to decide where to load the module. When you reload you will need to call `GetProcAddress` again for each function that you import, because the addresses of the functions may have changed, if the module has loaded at a different address.

Of course that part is missing from your code altogether. The part where you call `GetProcAddress` for every function that you import. You have to do it that way if you want to be able to reload. Otherwise the module might load at a different address and then everything falls over, as explained at the topic you linked to.

It looks as though you have been unlucky and the module is re-loaded at the same address. I say unlucky because you have not been able to observe the failure mode, and so are erroneously tempted into believing that your code is correct.

So you have to stop p/invoking directly to the module and obtain all function pointers by calling `GetProcAddress`. Convert these to delegates with `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

Comment: Did you mean "Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer"? :)

Comment: Yes I did. Brain freeze.