# How to unload a dll in C# imported via DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, dll, load, unload

I am currently working on a plugin dll für a 3rd party app.
This plugin dll is written in C#.
The plugin dll uses c++ dll and imports its functions via DllImport.

Every time I recompile the c++ dll while the 3rd party app is running, the compiler mentions:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cpp.dll'

Then I have to close the 3rd party app.
Unloading the plugin dll seems to be not enough.
When the 3rd party app is closed I can recompile cpp.dll

Question:
What do I have to do in my C# code, so that the cpp.dll is unloaded every time the plugin.dll is unloaded and so that I dont not have to close the 3rd party app ?

I tried to find solutions to unload cpp.dll but was not successful or the suggested solution do not seem to be reliable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unload a DLL loaded using DllImport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445536/unload-a-dll-loaded-using-dllimport)

Comment: No because it does not address the problem with the 3rd party app and the solutions suggested here do not seem to be reliable.

Comment: Sounds like the third party app itself is using cpp.dll, and it seems it's also using a non-sharing file handle on it (which it really shouldn't do) preventing you compiling. Maybe compile against another copy of cpp.dll?

Comment: Well the cpp.dll is imported via my c# code (my plugin dll). Since I do not know what the 3rd party app does (it is an application like e.g. OBS), is there a way to find out what happens gere ?